# MySQL Normal Text to Spinal Case Convertion

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table colum with general text values ex:

```
"This is Gerald's Sample Text: With some special chars"
```

I need to convert this text to:

```
"this-is-geralds-sample-text-with-some-special-chars"
```

with MySQL InnoDB and save the value in a separate unique column in the same table. Is there a simpler way of achieving this with a query without using procedures?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6216513/57191

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Please see my edited question!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No". You're looking for something that behaves exactly like a regular expression, and MySQL does not support regex replace natively.

The longer answer is "No, but there are workarounds." You have a couple of options, and I don't terribly like either. [The first is to create a function like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). The second is to come up with a list of bad characters and then use a set of `REPLACE` calls. It's ugly, but it will work.

On a side note: you might consider creating this value with your application and then just store along with the original. That would be cleaner in some ways than using a custom MySQL function.